# Significance of 631138519 in `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age'

Tags: http-headers

I see many websites sets the value of `631138519` (for example [twitter](https://securityheaders.com/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com&followRedirects=on)) for the security header `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age`.

That's roughly getting converted to 7,304.84 days or 175,316.26 hours. What's the significance of the number in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

631138519 seconds is 20 years, if an average year is 365.2421985 days long. Where does that number of days come from? I'm not sure, but it seems to represent the [tropical year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year) to an arbitrary degree of precision.

If I had to guess, I'd say that someone picked 20 years as a really long time, then looked up the number of days in a year and happened to see that value. Then other sites just copied the first one.

Comment: Makes Sense. Thanks Kevin!